# What packages do I use to create a visualization dashboard in IPython Notebook?

Tags: python, data-visualization, jupyter-notebook, dashboard

I'm looking to create a visualization dashboard to display **"site search analysis"** in Ipyhton notebook in a presentable format and need to know what modules or packages should I use to accomplish that?

***-What I've done already?***
I'm able to create the plots using matplotlib library. The charts that Ive plotted are pretty simple line graphs/histograms like "Unique search term and their frequencies","Most used search term of the day" and so on

***-What I need?***
I need to create a GUI/Dashboard where I can put these charts along with other controls like timeframe(1m | 1day | current),refresh etc. so that this can be used to gauge the **real-time** state of the site.

***References*** - This is a sample dashboard that I'm looking to replicate in Ipyhton -https://apps.sematext.com/sa-reports/mainPage.do?selectedApplication=13

Please help! What modules/packages should I use to do this quickly in Python?

Comment: Anyone who can help on this?!

Comment: Does [this article](http://moderndata.plot.ly/create-a-plotly-dashboards-in-under-10-minutes/) on Python dashboards help? You might also consider [IPython widgets](http://moderndata.plot.ly/widgets-in-ipython-notebook-and-plotly/); a cool example in [this Notebook](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/11/11/the-hipster-effect-interactive/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try [bowtie](https://github.com/jwkvam/bowtie) (as a disclaimer, I'm the author).

It has support for matplotlib using SVG elements.

https://bowtie-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components.html#svg

You can easily add control elements like buttons and date pickers to the dashboard as well. Just look for the control widgets in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

try this, :  https://github.com/litaotao/IPython-Dashboard

A stand alone, light-weight web server for building, sharing graphs created in ipython. Build for data science, data analysis guys. Building an interactive visualization, collaborated dashboard, and real-time streaming graph